# Rails: How do I validate uniqueness of certain types in an enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I have a model with the following enum:

```
# Schema
# account_type :integer, not null

enum account_type: {
  user: 1,
  deposit: 2,
  withdrawal: 3,
  fee: 4
}
```

I have to make sure that only one `:deposit`, `:withdrawal`, and `:fee` account exist, but allow an unlimited number of `:user` accounts. How can I do with this a model validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validates :account_type, uniqueness: true, if: 'account_type == "user"'
```

The answer was based on @neydroid's answer, although that per se was incorrect, and he didn't respond to my request to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a conditional to the uniqueness validation

```
validates :account_type, uniqueness: true, if: '!account_type.user?'
```

Comment: short and sweet, but this doesn't work, adding a `?` in the conditional throws a syntax error. Change your answer's conditional to `'account_type == "user"'` and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :only_one_of_most_account_types

  def only_one_of_most_account_types
    return if account_type == 1
    match = MyModel.find_by(account_type: account_type)
    errors.add(:account_type, "Already have one of these") if match && match.id != id
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case as `account_type` is an `enum` you can directly use the provided helper `user?`

```
validates :account_type, uniqueness: true, if: :user?
```